# Need a help with jquery script

Tags: jquery

i am doing a count down from the current server time until a specified time , at the moment the script is static when the visitor enter the web site he sees the timer counting down lets say from 1 day 20 hours 11 mins and 10 seconds and when refresh he starts counting down from the same value . here is the script

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$('#countdown_dashboard').countDown({
serverDate: {
'day':   20,
'month':  9,
'year':  2011,
'hour':  24,
'min':   0,
'sec':   0,
'serverDay':   11,    # current server day
'serverMonth':  9,    # current server month  
'serverYear':  2011,  # current server year
'serverHour':  19,    # current server hour
'serverMin':   10,    # current server min
'serverSec':   08     # current server second
},
omitWeeks: true
});
});
</script>
```

i need you to put the currunt time of server in day and month and year and hour and min and sec into variable so i can put them above in order not to make the visitor see the same timer happens again and again with no chnage

***** the server side language is PHP

Comment: Select your code and press Control-K to format it. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: here is the code , i really need to use the serve time .

Comment: You did not share very very crucial information: what is the server side language? By the way, the negative points are because of the "i need you to.." part in your question.

Comment: Fix your question title please. It does not describe the problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

add `until`

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$('#countdown_dashboard').countDown({
serverDate: {
'day':   20,
'month':  9,
'year':  2011,
'hour':  24,
'min':   0,
'sec':   0,
'serverDay':   11,    # current server day
'serverMonth':  9,    # current server month  
'serverYear':  2011,  # current server year
'serverHour':  19,    # current server hour
'serverMin':   10,    # current server min
'serverSec':   08     # current server second
},
omitWeeks: true
}, 
until: new Date(2012, 8 - 1, 8));
});
</script>
```

insert [desired js date object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp) instead...